# How to Create an AutoComplete in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

What I have here is a function where I call the **codigo**, and the **nombre**, in the DB
  table registrations. What I want to achieve is that the digital code that is like an autocomplete to fill in the name when you select the code.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELf1a.png)

```
class Matriculas extends Component {
  state = {
    status: "initial",
    data: []

  }
       componentDidMount = () => {
     this. getInfo()
     }

  getInfo= async () => {
    try {
      const response = await getAll('matriculas')
      console.log(response.data)
      this.setState({
        status: "done",
        data: response.data

      });
    } catch (error) {
      this.setState({
        status: "error"
      });
    }
  };
  render() {
    const data = [...this.state.data];
    return (

    <Container>
      <RowContainer margin="1px" >
        <ColumnContainer margin="10px">
          <h3>Info</h3>
          <label>Codigo</label>
          <Input
            width='150px'
            type="text"
            placeholder="Digite el codigo"
            value={data.codigo } ref="codigo" />
          <label>Nombre</label>
          <Input
            width='150px'
            type="text"
            placeholder="Nombre completo"
            value={data.nombre} />
        </ColumnContainer>
      </RowContainer>
    </Container>

    )
  }
};

export default Matriculas;
```

Comment: Please, translate the title of this question to English?

Comment: @Ele you can help me?

Answer (score 0):

What you most likely want to use is [react-select](https://react-select.com/home)

You can pass options to the select (which would be your names) and it will return values that match whatever you type in the search bar.

```
import Select from 'react-select'

const options = [
  { value: 'mike', label: 'Mike' },
  { value: 'john', label: 'John' },
  { value: 'vanessa', label: 'Vanessa' }
]

const MyComponent = () => (
  <Select options={options} />
)
```

So you can take that example, and the examples in the link, and put it in your code:

```
import Select from 'react-select'

<Container>
      <RowContainer margin="1px" >
        <ColumnContainer margin="10px">
          <h3>Info</h3>
          <label>Codigo</label>
          <Input
            width='150px'
            type="text"
            placeholder="Digite el codigo"
            value={data.codigo } ref="codigo" />
          <label>Nombre</label>
          <Select 
           value={this.state.nameValue}
           onChange={event => {this.setState({nameValue: e.value})}
           options={options} />
        </ColumnContainer>
      </RowContainer>
    </Container>
```

When using onChage, it returns an `event`, which has the value of the selected name. You can use that to set the state's nameValue, and then use that name value in the rest of your component as well

Once you get this up and running, it also worth looking at the [async select](https://react-select.com/home#async), which allows you to give an async function that returns values (your `getInfo` function, for example)

*-- edit --*

If you want to define the onChange event elsewhere, it would look like this:

```
handleChange = event => {
  // event.value will be the value of the select
  this.setState({optionSelected: event.value});
}
```

and then in your onChange, tell it that is the function you want but *do not* invoke it (don't write it with parentheses):

```
<Select 
   value={this.state.optionSelected}
    onChange={this.handleChange}
    options={options} />
```

Comment: Hey  thanks my friend .Excellent! ... I have the Select, with which when I select an Option, I pass the value to another input, but I have another problem. I no longer store the data of the Select, Before yes.
Now I use this:
value={this.state.selectedOption}
 onChange = {this.handleChange()}  
el select es:
<Select
value={this.state.selectedOption}
onChange = { this.handleChange() }
options={aircrafts}
name={"registration"} 
/>
the handleChange event is:
 handleChange = (selectedOption) =>
{
this.setState({
 selectedOption, name:  selectedOption.value //send value
});
}

Comment: Before I used this event and value in the input
const flight = this.state.flight
<Input type="text" onChange={this.handleForm('registration')}
value={flight.registration}  />
As before, before if you stored the data, because it used value = "flight.registration"
The handleForm event is..
handleForm = (propertyName) => (event) => {
const value = event.target.type === 'checkbox' ? event.target.checked : event.target.value;
const { flight } = Object.assign({}, this.state);
const newFlight = {
 ...flight,
[propertyName]: value
};
this.setState({ flight: newFlight })
 }

Comment: @json so when you you pass in a function to onChage, you can't invoke it. (You have onChange={this.handleChange()}, this is wrong. You want it to be onchange={this.handleChange}, you only pass the function, and you in your handleChange function defintion, have it take event as a parameter